# image crop not detected by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, image

when I resize or crop an image using `$this->image_lib->crop()` via ajax, the image manipulation process itself worked as expected.. but when I try to show the resulting image using `$('#someDivId').css('background-image', 'url('+res.filepath+')');`, the image shown is not cropped.. is it because ajax synchronization or something? please help..

P.S. I'm using jquery ver 1.12.4 and codeigniter 3

the ajax call I used looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/mymodule/resize_img',
  type: 'post',
  data: $('form').serializeArray(),
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(res) {
    $('#someDivId').css('background-image', 'url('+res.filepath+')');
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: I take it `res.filepath` points to the correct (cropped) image? which you've verified by opening it directly in the browser?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, that's correct

Answer (score 0):

my friend suggested a solution and it works.

he suspected that the image was cached by the server or browser. so he told me to use an extra parameter when referring to the image path like this:

changed this:

`$('#someDivId').css('background-image', 'url('+res.filepath+')');`

into this:

```
var n = Math.random();
var newImgPath = res.filepath + '?x=' + n;
$('#someDivId').css('background-image', 'url('+newImgPath+')');
```

such a silly yet annoying thing..